# I cannot action double click with uiautomator (Android)

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, android-espresso, uitest

```
UiObject buylist = new UiObject(new UiSelector().withText("buy"));

Configurator cc = Configurator.getInstance();
cc.setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(40);
buylist.click();
buylist.click();
```

In my application, if you double click at buy button, it will alert the popup message. So, this code cannot action like that. It works as single click two times and not alert anything. Please, help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Use Thread.sleep(time in ms) for the delay between the click events and try. It should work. An issue may be occurred due to less default time between the view clicks.

Comment: yes, double clicking is nothing but two single clicks with slight delay in between.